# PDF: zoom with scroll wheel and pan

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Is it possible to set a PDF document using Adobe Acrobat 9 or 10 so that:

- Using the mouse's scroll wheel will zoom
- Holding left-click will pan

It's an intuitive interface, kind of like Google Maps, that I would use with some PDFs...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about graphic design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acrobat has similar behavior built in.  If you scroll mousewheel while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (on Windows, not sure the Mac key), you will zoom in and out.  If you hold <kbd>Space</kbd> while click-dragging, you will pan around the document.

(This is how it behaves in Acrobat X. I believe the behavior is the same in older versions though I don't have any present to test.)

Comment: The Mac key is `Alt`.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to know if it's possible to set this as a document behavior. Zoom and pan behaviors are controlled by the reader (whether Adobe Reader or Acrobat or some 3rd party solution), so in a regular PDF that would not be possible.

You could embed a SWF that had this capability, though. You would have to create it with Flash Professional and include it in the PDF either via InDesign or directly in Acrobat. If you have access to a good javascript coder, that might be another approach. It's not something you can do natively in the Acrobat UI.

Always be aware, though, that very few PDF readers implement all of the PDF specification, so your results are likely to be unpredictable at best and most likely would work only in Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on the document, an option pops up for HAND TOOL.
The hand tool works like Google Maps, etc.
It zooms with the scroll wheel and pans with a click-and-hold.

I keep forgetting where it is hidden, and just checked here. . . probably be back to find my own answer soon!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Edit > preferences > general</kbd>, check the `make hand tool use mouse-wheel zooming` check box.

Comment: Mike, excellent answer. Do you know if this answer changes for Mac users?

Answer (score 0):

Find the toolbar that has a `continuous zoom` button (not sure which toolbar).
Click that, and you can zoom with the wheel pan pan by holding the wheel down.

Answer (score 0):

View/Preferences/General - then tick "Make Select tool use mouse-wheel zooming".

I know its old, but when I was looking for it - this was top of Google search, without an answer ! I found the solution and came back.

Happy acrobating !

Comment: Isn't the the same solution in Mike's answer?